# html5 audio play many times

Tags: jquery, html, audio

```
var audio = new Audio('click.mp3');
$("nav li").mouseover(function() {
  audio.play();
}).mouseout(function() {
  audio.pause(); 
});
```

Here is my code, on hover the audio file plays many times, I want to know what to add to make it play only once on hover not many times

Comment: Might be propagating https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: you can use mouseenter instead of mouseover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var audio = new Audio('click.mp3');
var hasBeenPlayed = false;
$("nav li").mouseover(function() {
  if(!hasBeenPlayed) {
  audio.play();
  hasBeenPlayed = true;
}
}).mouseout(function() {
  audio.pause();
  hasBeenPlayed = false; 
});
```